# CouchApp cannot retrieve key/value pairs from view but Futon can

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I create a simple couchapp and deployed it into my CouchDB instance. However, i'm noticing an anomaly. The view created (via couchapp generate view ...) returns data when I view it in CouchDB's Futon administrative interface (logged in as admin), but not when I run the couchapp I wrote. Here's an example of my code:

```
$.CouchApp(function(app) {
app.view("wine_list", { success: function(json) {
    json.rows.map(function(row) {
       alert(row.key);
    }); 
}});
});
```

The result I get out of alert() above is 'null'.

And when I navigate to: http://localhost:5984/winedb/_design/wineapp/_view/wine_list I get:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":null,"value":null}
  ]}
```

But, If I open Futon admin interface and navigate to the design doc/view, I can see records. Now, in Futon i'm logged in as admin. So, my guess is I should specific auth credentials in my couchapp javascript code? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your view has both a *map* and *reduce* component, then this might be a user interface bug in Futon.

By default, CouchDB will supply *map and reduce* results to queries. To see only the map results, you must provide a `?reduce=false` parameter.

By default, Futon provides the `?reduce=false` parameter, and you have to check the "reduce" checkbox to get the "default" behavior.

In other words, add `reduce=false` to your query. Does that help?

Comment: What if I want to get the rows that are returned when reduce is set to 'true'?